# How to convert the object with only modified properties values, remaining values should be null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, azure-worker-roles

Using Reflection I got the collection of modified columns for the Object.

```
IEnumerable<string> modified = GetModifiedColumns();
```

I would like to modify the object like below

```
 EmployeeModel model = new EmployeeModel
        {
            Id = 1000, //This one must 
            FirstName = modfiedValue,
            Email = null, 
            LastName = null,
            Phone = null
        };
```

This model I will be sending to the worker role and update the Entity with only modified values. This way I would like to reduce the traffic on the wire.

I can use like below, Its working. But its not a efficient approach

```
var empModel = GetOnlyUpdatedColumns(modified , model);     

private EmployeeModel GetOnlyUpdatedColumns(IEnumerable<string> modified , EmployeeModel emp)
    {
EmployeeModel model = new EmployeeModel
        {
            Id = emp.Id, //This one must 
            FirstName =  (modified.Contains("FirstName"))? emp.FirstName:null,
            Email = (modified.Contains("FirstName"))? emp.FirstName:null,
            LastName = (modified.Contains("LastName"))? emp.LastName:null,
            Phone = (modified.Contains("Phone"))? emp.Phone:null,
        };
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: well. I would like to have only modified values in the model, remaining  properties to keep as null value.

Comment: Modification tracking is difficult, and there aren't really many *short* examples for it - and it gets increasingly hard for things that aren't a single flat object

Comment: My concerns is some of the model will have more than 100 properties, Then I need to check each property that is modified or not.